# how do you reverse scrolling...so it goes from bottom to top?

Tags: javascript

Today at my internship i got asked to make that the website they wanna make...is red from bottom to top.
tbh i have never seen such a website...
So let's put aside all the UI/UX problems this summons 
how you you make make it, so were you land is the bottom of the page, and make the scrolling down actually scroll up?
(or so)

Answer (score 1):

Keep the ready solution on jQuery (this works, but this is workpiece, you need to improve to interact with the scroll in the nested blocks):

```
function onScroll(velocity) {
  var win = $(window)  
  $(win).on('wheel', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var direction = event.originalEvent.deltaY > 0? 'down': 'up';    
    var position = win.scrollTop();

    if (direction === 'up') {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: (position + velocity)
        }, 40);
    }
    else if (direction === 'down') {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: (position - velocity)
        }, 40);
    }
  })
}
onScroll(70);
```

Also, the code can be simplified, I did not do it intelligently for clarity

[live example](https://codepen.io/eneymotorny/pen/ZRZNjq)